# Layered navigation showing child brands with bundles

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.0.1, layered-navigation, bundled-product

Using Magento 1.9.1 and have a problem with Layered navigation and bundle product brands.

I have many simple products that can be part of any bundle product. All of them can be with different manufacturer (brand). If they are part of a bundle, they are marked as "Not visible individually".

I make a new Bundle product, and set some of the simple products as part of the bundle. I also set manufacturer for the bundle product that is different from the children.

In my layered navigation i can see the manufacturer for the bundle product, but also all children. And I would only want to show manufacturer of the bundle.

Only if a simple product is marked as visible in Catalogue, it would show up in the layered navigation.

How do I filter children manufacturer from layered navigation if the child is marked as "not visible individually"?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider creating 2 separate attributes.

One attribute is "Manufacturer (not visible" and set it as not used in the layered navigation.

And one attribute as just "Manufacturer", set it as Filtered (with results)

Comment: Not working for this type, because then some of the children can be visible as individual items also. My original post was not totally correct on this point...